# How to access cmd.exe from ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, batch-file, iis

I'm currently working on a website using ASP.NET MVC, and I'm trying to allow the user to access cmd.exe through the website and run some commands in it. Here's what I have tried:

```
Dim command As String = "msg %username% Hello World!"

Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
Dim p As Process = New Process()
pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
pi.Arguments = command
pi.UseShellExecute = False
p.StartInfo = pi
p.Start()
```

Unfortunately, when I try to test it using my local IIS, nothing seems to be happening and nothing is displayed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with IIS? I really have zero clue now

Comment: Any VB code in your web application is executed on the server so this couldn't possibly help a user viewing the site in a browser, possibly on the other side of the world to the web server. If what you wanted was possible, it would have to be invoked via script but web sites are almost always prevented from accessing resources on the user's local machine for security reasons. What you want is simply not possible with a regular web site. You really ought to learn how web applications work.

Comment: This command will be run on the server, not the client. The user running the server doesn't have access do cmd. Would could create a process on the server that can run command and have the web user call this process.

Comment: If I create a new local user with administrator privilege, and give this user enough privileges to execute batch scripts, then select this user as the AppPool user in IIS, could it possibly work?

Comment: @JessicaSong Can you elaborate on why you want to do this? Perhaps there is a way that isn't quite so dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the **client** `%username%` in a command line process on the **server**.  Username will be the logged in user on the server (which probably isn't be the user name that you want).

What you want is to use the `User` property of the controller.  This will be the current logged in user in ASP.Net (if there is one).